# Is It Possible delegate in java?

Tags: java, c#

-how to handle Events by methods in java like c# .

We use as public delegate void Event(); 
how is this Possible in java ?

Comment: Hmm...the person who upvoted this should perhaps read _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_ along with the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare delegate By Interface in Java 
Like :

```
     public interface Behaviour
{
   void function()
}

// in java
public class ABehaviour implements Behaviour
{
   public void function()
   {
      // TypeA behaviour
   }
}

public class BBehaviour implements Behaviour
{
   public void function()
   {
      // TypeB behaviour
   }
}

// In Java
Behaviour someBehaviour= new ABehaviour();
someBehaviour.function();
someBehaviour = new BBehaviour ();
someBehaviour.function();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173171.aspx.

It is the version of a delegate, so for an event you should be able to just do:

```
delegate void buttonClickEvent(eventArgs e, object sender)
```

That should allow you to use another method for that in a subsequent class.

You would also need to add the event to the listeners for that event.

The other thing that you might want to look into is interfaces. That might also give you what you want.

P.S. please tell me if any of this is wrong I'm on the train currently without access to my computer